# AFNetworking 2 migration for imageProcessingBlock:

Tags: ios

I am migrating to AFNetworking 2
What is the replacement of

```
[AFImageRequestOperation imageRequestOperationWithRequest:request imageProcessingBlock:
     ^UIImage *(UIImage *downloadedImage) {
         return [NIImageProcessing imageFromSource:downloadedImage
                                   withContentMode:contentMode
                                          cropRect:cropRect
                                       displaySize:displaySize
                                      scaleOptions:self.scaleOptions
                              interpolationQuality:self.interpolationQuality];

     } success:^(NSURLRequest *successfulRequest, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *processedImage) {
         [self _didFinishLoadingWithImage:processedImage
                          cacheIdentifier:pathToNetworkImage
                              displaySize:displaySize
                              contentMode:contentMode
                             scaleOptions:self.scaleOptions
                           expirationDate:nil];

     } failure:^(NSURLRequest *errorRequest, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
         [self _didFailToLoadWithError:error];
     }];
```

This is from Nimbus ---> NINetworkImageView.m

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

In AFNetworking 2.0 you should use AFHTTPRequestOperation's property

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) AFHTTPResponseSerializer <AFURLResponseSerialization> * responseSerializer;
```

to set the way how response should be serialized. In your case you need `AFImageResponseSerializer`:

```
operation.responseSerializer = [AFImageResponseSerializer serializer];
```

To set completion block use AFHTTPRequestOperation's method:

```
- (void)setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject))success
                              failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure;
```

To create operation you also can use AFHTTPRequestOperationManager's method

```
- (AFHTTPRequestOperation *)GET:(NSString *)URLString
                     parameters:(id)parameters
                        success:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject))success
                        failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure
```

UPDATE:

If you want to have custom image processing logic you should create a `AFImageResponseSerializer`s subclass and implement method

```
- (id)responseObjectForResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
                           data:(NSData *)data
                          error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error
```

For example:

```
@interface MyImageResponseSerializer : AFImageResponseSerializer 
@end

@implementation MyImageResponseSerializer
- (id)responseObjectForResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
                           data:(NSData *)data
                          error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error
{
     UIImage *img = [super responseObjectForResponse:response
                           data:data
                          error:error];
     // add a watermark to img or do something else
     return img;
}

@end
```

and then set it to operation's `responseSerializer` property

```
operation.responseSerializer = [MyImageResponseSerializer serializer];
```

Comment: yes i understand but where to place the imageProcessingBlock:

Comment: @user3427687, I have updated the answer. I have not tested it but I hope it does not have serious mistakes.

Comment: @user3427687 please do not forget to accept/upvote the answer if it was useful.

Answer (score 0):

Thank God, its solved

I checked the recent Nimbus which is using AFNetworking 2.2

Steps :

1: Copied the NIImageResponseSerializer Class .h and .m file from the latest project.

2: Copied the following 4 functions from the latest project.

- (void)setPathToNetworkImage:(NSString *)pathToNetworkImage forDisplaySize:(CGSize)displaySize contentMode:(UIViewContentMode)contentMode cropRect:(CGRect)cropRect
- (NSString *)cacheKeyForCacheIdentifier:(NSString *)cacheIdentifier
                             imageSize:(CGSize)imageSize
                              cropRect:(CGRect)cropRect
                           contentMode:(UIViewContentMode)contentMode
                          scaleOptions:(NINetworkImageViewScaleOptions)scaleOptions
- (NSDate *)expirationDate
- (void)_didFinishLoadingWithImage:(UIImage *)image
                 cacheIdentifier:(NSString *)cacheIdentifier
                     displaySize:(CGSize)displaySize
                        cropRect:(CGRect)cropRect
                     contentMode:(UIViewContentMode)contentMode
                    scaleOptions:(NINetworkImageViewScaleOptions)scaleOptions
                  expirationDate:(NSDate *)expirationDate

Thats it.
For reference I was migrating to AFNetworking 2.2 which was added to my project earlier and I am using Nimbus(Old Version) for Horizontal Photo Scroll feature.